# Allow CORS for static content in MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cors

I have an ASP.NET MVC application which runs on www.domain.com (always www). My static domain runs on static.domain.com.

Right now I am setting Access-Control-Allow-Origin to "*" in Web.Config:

```
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
```

However, obviously this is not good practice. So I tried adding the following:

```
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="//static.domain.com"/>
```

To allow any protocols (which is what I ideally want, or if I could add two rules, one for http and one for https). This didn't work, so I also tried with http:// protocol.

```
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://static.domain.com"/>
```

which did not work either.

I've read through similar threads/questions here at stackoverflow, but everything i find suggests to add the domain as i did in the last example "http://static.domain.com"...

I must be doing something wrong, but I can't seem to get what that is. Hope you can help me!

Thanks in advance!

Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this is similar to other posts answers. It simply is not possible through only the web.config. It needs to be set programmatically in the Global.asax.cs file.

This is done by adding some lines of code in the Application_EndRequest() method in Global.asax.cs file. I extracted the code into a method, but you can put the code straight inside if you wish.

```
string[] domains = {"static.domain.com", "domain.com"}; // Personally I get this from a config

if (Request != null || Request.Headers != null || Response != null || Response.Headers != null)
{    
  string host = Request.Headers["Host"]; // This doesn't care about protocol

  if (domains.Where(domain => domain == host).Count() > 0)
    Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  else
    Response.Headers.Remove("Access-Control-Allow-Origin");
}
```

This works great, since the `Request.Headers["Host"]` does not get the protocol, we can just check if there is any match with our string array, the we set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin to allow everything, otherwise we remove it. So in a way, we are dynamically setting the key.

This needs to be in the Global.asax.cs since it needs to be on EVERY request (since we need to use this for all resource files as well).